Under EU law, is it a trademark violation to mention other products by name in a description?
I'm working on a game where if people have at least passing familiarity with Yahtzee (UK/US) or Kniffel (Germany), they'd have a good idea how to play this.
Would I be within my right to name-drop these trademarked names in the rules/back of the box, or would that lead to legal issues?
I'm not claiming to be affiliated with their products, I'm not trying to sell myself as a competitor or damage their trademark, simply use it as a basis of comparison for readers to associate with.
Would this be ok under EU law? I know that US trademark law has some provisions fo things like these, but I'm not sure how it works in Europe.
Furthermore, do I need to include the ® symbol next to the names? I.e. Yahtzee® and Kniffel®?

Does this answer your question? Can a company use another brand's name when describing their product?

@Sneftel no because that's US law. I'm interested in EU law

The problem is that you are not allowed to use other trademarks to advance your own product.
Nowadays, cases like this involve tagging things in app stores. So for example you are not allowed to tag your game "kniffel", even if you make it abundantly clear that it isn't, because you used their trademark to drive users to your product through the search. They typed in "kniffel" and your product popped up.
I would assume the back of a cardboard box in a brick and mortar store would be the same legally. You use another trademark to influcence a consumer to buy your product. That is not allowed.
Look at all the products that are compatible with LEGO. None of them are allowed (*) to print "compatible with LEGO". Even if that is a simple fact.

(*)
You could argue that they might be, just that nobody had the money to fight a case through all instances until you reach an actually independent and knowledgable judge. And in theory that is great, but I am assuming that the OP is not that deep pocket millionaire, and if you cannot get a judgement in your favor, it doesn't really matter whether you are right or not.

Cases:
Rescuecom_Corp. v. Google Inc. for the US
LUSH vs Amazon for the UK
(yes, I know, technically, the UK is not in the EU anymore. But it's the language everybody here understands and the laws haven't changed since then.)

This must be different in the US. In pharmacies, store-brand drugs often have "compare with " prominent on the packaging. But maybe they're actually licensing the name when they re-brand the products.

N @barmar this answer is wrong

@Tak I have linked you not one, but two cases with names that are certainly not small players. Do you think those are wrong? In what way?

So you're saying NullSignal Games' "Compatible with Netrunner" cards are technically illegal? I'm sure their lawyers have checked this through

@ElectricCoffee I am not familiar with them. Do they market it as such in the EU? What would be the active trademark they legally use with no agreement? Both WotC and Talsorian trademarks on the word "Netrunner" expired.

One could add in the caveat that you could mention the other trademarks if you have an agreement with the owners of the other trademarks. A LEGO compatible product could definitely say 'compatible with LEGO' if they have an agreement with LEGO allowing them to say so.

@nvoigt I mean it's an online store, but they sell to and within the EU so yeah they do. Maybe it's ok because the trademark expired. Either way, I wonder if it's advancing the product to give people a point of familiarity. "If you know how to play UNO you know how to play this". I guess it is since without that point it wouldn't be as attractive to those who aren't familiar

Well, the actual cases I know are about using it as search term, which is undoubtably driving traffic using someone elese's trademark. I don't know any case about for example printing it in a manual you only get once you bought the box. But as I said in regards to LEGO, if the other company has a zealous lawyer and enough resources, you might just not get what you deserve. If no case is ever brought because nobody wants to take that risk, I guess it's an answer of it's own.

The fair use doctrine allows for trademarked names to be legally used under specific circumstances.
Nominative Fair Use
Nominative fair use means that a trademarked name can be used to refer to products and make comparisons in certain circumstances. Under nominative fair use, the trademark should usually be used only as much as needed to illustrate the point and can not be used to claim an association with the owner of the trademark.
Simply using the name of a game is nominative fair use as long as there is no claim to be associated with the other games. You also can not use the trademarked name excessively without a reason.
Normally, when another company uses someone's trademarked name it is to point out differences in the products. When saying the games are similar, there probably should be something pointing out some way your game is different to avoid sounding too much like other games.

Like the old "Pepsi vs. Coke" ads. There was no chance of confusion that the Coca Cola Corporation was endorsing Pepsico.

Fair use is copyright terminology. Nominative use is trademark terminology. You've confounded the two.

@ohwilleke cite something saying that. Fair use is a term widely used in trade mark cases.

IIRC EU doesn't have "fair use"

@ElectricCoffee what are you basing that from

@Tak a quick google search can tell you all that.

@ohwilleke: The US courts regularly use the "Nominative Fair Use" phrasing.  E.g., the Manual of Model Civil Jury Instructions includes 15.25 Defenses—Nominative Fair Use.
